# javascript - pushing new property to objects that are in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I got an array person containing many objects that look like this:

```
const person = [
{ first: 'firstName', last: 'lastName', year: 1439, passed: 1495 },
 ...
]
```

I have counted how many years the person lived:

```
const oldest = person.map(x => x.passed - x.year);
```

Got new array with the years for every person.

Now I would like to push this calculated year as a new property age to each person object in this array.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add a new property

```
person.forEach(p => p.lifetime = p.passed - p.year);
```

Or map a new array of objects

```
persons = person.map(p => ({ ...p, lifetime: p.passed - p.year });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property directly by assigning value To it like this

Person[0].age = oldest[0]:

You can loop like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which will iterate through the same array and you can create a new property to the same array.

If you want get a new array you can use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which will create a new array.

I hope this will solve the issue.

```js
const person = [
{ first: 'firstName', last: 'lastName', year: 1439, passed: 1489 },
{ first: 'secondName', last: 'lastName', year: 1499, passed: 1590 },

{ first: 'thirdName', last: 'lastName', year: 1539, passed: 1570 },

{ first: 'fourthName', last: 'lastName', year: 1993, passed: 2018 },

]


person.forEach(obj => obj["age"] = obj.passed - obj.year)


console.log("same array with added age property", person)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both arrays `person` and `oldest` have the same length, you can just iterate over either, construct new objects with `age` properties from the elements of both arrays at the same index and push them to a result array.

```js
const person = [
  { first: 'firstName', last: 'lastName', year: 1439, passed: 1495 }
];

const oldest = person.map(x => x.passed - x.year);

const result = [];
person.forEach(({first, last, year, passed}, i) => result.push({first, last, year, passed, age: oldest[i]}));

console.log(result);
```

Given a `zip` function (which unfortunately is not yet standard JavaScript), you could also shorten this to:

```
zip(person, oldest).map(([{first last, year, passed}, age]) => ({first, last, year, passed, age}));
```